Java NIO2 Selector.select(long) for streaming
Is it advisable to use Java NIO2 Selector.select(timeout) to continuously stream data to the network where timeout can range from 1-5 milliseconds for video/audio streaming (700 pps max) to 3 minutes for sending simple pings?
The program can also run separate Threads to stream different types of data to channels, but the Selector is one thread that can manage streaming to all channels.

I would just use multiple threads and blocking sockets for sending the videos. Just write as much as you can as fast as you can and let TCP take care of the pacing.

@user207421

Should I use TCP, or UDP or UDP-multicast to write video/audio to multiple destinations?
Why to use blocking sockets for streaming?


(a) depends on whether you need reliability. (b) because it's much simpler than non-blocking NIO, detection of short writes, use of OP_WRITE, &c &c &c.

@user207421 I can use TCP/UDP/Multicast for network transport just by changing the configuration, got your advice about reliability, thanks. My client-server is fast, non-blocking, stable, no need to worry about technically simpler code.
Meanwhile, everything looks good. The tricky part is I guess I need to implement a standard protocol for video/audio streaming, or can the program just read the bytes from the video file and stream the bytes "as is" to the viewer?

I believe for video people don't care about lost or duplicated or out of sequence packets: they just stream the bytes.

@user207421 Why internet radios use different protocols, are there standard protocols, when to use protocols (audio/video)? What about streaming secure content?
